# logic for not exists in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is sql equivalent

```
 SELECT TOP 1  filed1 FROM tab  
WHERE f1 = @lngTransactionId 
AND f2 = 'R' AND f3 = ''
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM tab GV WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE f1 = @lngTransactionId 
AND f2 = 'R' AND f3 = 'R')
```

I tried this way

```
db.collection.find( { "$and" : [ { "f1":4525 }, { "f2" : "R" } , { "f3" :  "" } , 
                              {"$nor" : [ { "f1":4525 }, { "f2" : "R" } , { "f3" :  "R" } ]}]
                              })
```

It is not giving the expected result.

How to achieve that condition in that not exits in sql in a single mongo query.

Comment: A query/find works with a single document at a time in MongoDB. It appears your SQL query is really doing two distinct queries. Find X, but only when there isn't a second X with Y also true. Have you had a look at the aggregation framework?

Comment: Can you show more information about the document structure and what result you are expecting?